# Background Files disabled in Trimble GeoXT

Tags: trimble

I am trying to send background shapefiles to the trimble GeoExplorer 2008 series. I have used GPS Pathfinder Office and sent the files in the correct coordinate system. Look at the picture I attached. The Geo7X clearly shows background files as an option. The GeoXT does not.[image]

Comment: Have you checked the Terrasync documentation for the version of Terrasync on the GeoXT? Those two handhelds are almost certainly not running the same version of Terrasync.

Comment: Can you clarify what the question actually is, the title mentions `disabled` does that mean you have documentation that says uploading files is theoretically possible in a GeoXT and you want to know how to enable this functionality, or is the question is it possible to upload files or is it how do you upload files?

Comment: The GeoXT has version 3.7 and the Geo7X has version 5.7.  My question is why can't I see the background files option on the GeoXT GPS? I am trying to load a background raster image and boundary. I am almost certain I have uploaded background files before on the GeoXT. This unit is pretty old so it has been a few years.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation for Terrasync v3.0](http://trl.trimble.com/docushare/dsweb/Get/Document-356361/TerraSyncReferenceManual.pdf), Background files are only available in Terrasync Professional. If you have the Standard version, you can't use Background files. The GeoXT probably has the Standard version.

> This option is not available in the TerraSync Standard edition
>   software. You can only open background files using the TerraSync
>   Professional edition software.